# Apollo Client useQuery making un-necessary refetches upon Next.js router.push

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo

I'm dealing with an issue in which a query inside a `useQuery` Apollo Client hook is getting un-necessarily re-run whenever Next.js's `router.push` ([docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush)) is called.

The abbreviated code is:

```
const Parent = () => {
  useQuery(QUERY_HERE, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      console.log("just completed apollo query");
    }
  });

  return <Child />;
}

const Child = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const currentArg = router.query?.currentArg;

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (currentArg === "on") {
            router.push("/?currentArg=off");
          } else {
            router.push("/?currentArg=on");
          }
        }}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[You can see a reproduction on CodeSandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-router-apollo-refetch-bug-d32umc?file=/pages/index.js)

My expectation is that whenever the button is clicked (and thus `router.push` is called), the query shouldn't be re-run. However, it's re-run any time the button is clicked. This is surprising because my understanding is that an Apollo query should only be re-run when one of its variables change.

Does anyone know of a way to ensure that the Apollo query is not re-run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js re-renders pages when navigation occurs and in your example you recreate Apollo Client every time it happens. Then your `useQuery` component renders again, checks if cache contains data for given query (it doesn't as new client is empty) and sends query again.

To fix this, create your `ApolloClient` in global scope. This way it'll stay stable and can be reused between multiple queries and renders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm currently defining the `ApolloClient` in a global `ApolloProvider` used by the entire component tree. Shouldn't that be "global" and retain its cache between component mounts?

Comment: According to your Sandbox you construct it while rendering `IndexPage` - it's not cached in any state or reference. Then `ApolloProvider` picks it up and passes down the tree.

Comment: Ah, that was it. By just putting the instantiation of the client _outside_ the render function, it retains the cache between renders.

Thank you so much sir.